# Can't find API Key under Authentication in Postman

Tags: api, authentication, postman, api-key

In postman, I was trying to test my API using token-based authentication using Postman. I generated a token for my user, but for testing it, I need to feed it as an API key in Postman. But I am not being able to find the API key option.
For understanding, I have added a screenshot of my Postman window along. [image: Please have a look.]

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a token and would like to use this to access a resource, right?

Comment: What type of token is it? You can also manually add the token as an Authorization header, in the Headers section. You're also running a really old version of the app there.

Comment: It's a Django Authentication Token, you use it as an API key to your API

Answer (score 4):

It is same for me and I solved with followings,

```
Go to "Headers" tab near "Authorization"
Put "Authorization" in "KEY" form
Put "Token xxxxxx" in "VALUE" form
```

Comment: Initially did not allow me to do it, saying ```"Authorization " is not a valid http header``` .  Notice the intentional  displayed space in the message Authorization in apostrophes. However picking up one of the available authorization types on the authorization tab and subsequently editing it on the Headers tab, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Plese try to download on your local machine, downloaded machine has the option you are looking for

https://www.postman.com/downloads/

Here is the related Documentation

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/#api-key

snapshot showing all authorization options

[image]